# MVC3 DDL Autopostback selection like

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ddl, autopostback

I know MVC doesn't have autoposback functionality and that needs to be done using JS/JQuery, and that is when my problems start... don't know how to do it yet.

This is how I populate my ddl:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentCountry,
                  new SelectList(Model.Countries.ToList(), "Code", "Name"))
```

and my URL have this format:

```
localhost/Products/?country=US&currency=USD&category=17&page=2
```

How do I add postback functionality to take the selected country?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know MVC doesn't have autoposback functionality and that needs to be done using JS/JQuery

Not necessary. You could put the dropdown in an HTML `<form>` and when the user submits this form the selected value will be sent to the server.

If on the other hand you want to transmit the selected value when the user changes selection then you need to use javascript and subscribe to the onchange event. For example if you use jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe to the change event of the dropdown
    $('#CurrentCountry').change(function() {
        // find the containing form and submit it
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @darin, thanks for that. That's what I need, a postback on SelectChange but how do I wire it up?

Comment: You subscribe to the .change event as I showed in my answer. This assumes that the dropdown list is inside a form. If it isn't you could either use AJAX or use `window.location.href` to redirect. Everything will depend on what you are trying to achieve.